# Xamarin.Forms Calling Dialog from Xamarin.Android Project Throws an Exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I've been trying to call a Dialog Alert from my xamarin.forms app using IoC container so far I haven't been able to display an alert in my app using this code:

Code at my viewModel:

```
await _dialogService.DisplayMessageAsync("ERROR", "There are errors on your form!", "Cancel", null);
```

at my shared project I have this DialogService which is the one I call from my viewModel:

```
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
    public DialogService()
    {
        _dialogService = DependencyService.Get<IDialogService>();
    }

    public void CloseAllDialogs()
    {
        _dialogService.CloseAllDialogs();
    }

    public async Task DisplayMessageAsync(string title, string message, string buttonCancelName, Action callback)
    {
        await _dialogService.DisplayMessageAsync(title, message, buttonCancelName, callback);
    }

    public async Task DisplayMessageConfirmAsync(string title, string message, string buttonOkName, string buttonCancelName, Action<bool> callback)
    {
        await _dialogService.DisplayMessageConfirmAsync(title, message, buttonOkName, buttonCancelName, callback);
    }
}
```

so at my Xamarin.Android.XXXXX I have the implementation of my DialogService which is call from my DialogService at my Shared Project this is the code:

```
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    List<AlertDialog> _openDialogs = new List<AlertDialog>();
    public void CloseAllDialogs()
    {
        foreach (var dialog in _openDialogs)
        {
            dialog.Dismiss();
        }
        _openDialogs.Clear();
    }

    public async Task DisplayMessageAsync(string title, string message, string okButton, Action callback)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Alert(title, message, okButton, callback));
    }

    public async Task DisplayMessageConfirmAsync(string title, string message, string okButton, string cancelButton, Action<bool> callback)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => AlertConfirm(title, message, okButton, cancelButton, callback));
    }

    bool Alert(string title, string content, string okButton, Action callback)
    {
        var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
        //var activity = (Activity)Android.App.Application.Context;
        var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context);
        //var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alert.SetTitle(title);
        alert.SetMessage(content);
        alert.SetNegativeButton(okButton, (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!Equals(callback, null))
            {
                callback();
            }
            _openDialogs.Remove((AlertDialog)sender);
        });

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            AlertDialog dialog = alert.Show();
            _openDialogs.Add(dialog);
            dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.SetCancelable(false);
        });

        return true;
    }

    bool AlertConfirm(string title, string content, string okButton, string cancelButton, Action<bool> callback)
    {
        var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context);
        alert.SetTitle(title);
        alert.SetMessage(content);
        alert.SetNegativeButton(cancelButton, (sender, e) =>
        {
            callback(false);
            _openDialogs.Remove((AlertDialog)sender);
        });
        alert.SetPositiveButton(okButton, (sender, e) =>
        {
            callback(true);
            _openDialogs.Remove((AlertDialog)sender);
        });

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            var dialog = alert.Show();
            _openDialogs.Add(dialog);
            dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.SetCancelable(false);
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

so whenever the private method alert is called it throws an Exception like this:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not valid; is your activity running?

it can be corrected if I switch this line of code:

```
var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context);
```

for this line of code:

```
var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
```

the problem of using this I get a Xamarin.Forms warning like this:

> 'Forms.Context' is obsolete: 'Context is obsolete as of version 2.5.
>   Please use a local context instead.'

and i'm a bit obsesive I dont like to have warning and try to maintain my code as updated as possible so, can somebody help me make this code work  without needing to use obsolete code. because I found answers that just replacing (Activity)Forms.Context for Android.App.Application.Context would work, but in this case it isn't working at all.

hopefully someone can point me in the right direction because i haven't been able to find any documentation about this case specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `Android.App.Application.Context` is not always an `Activity` Context.

Xamarin removed this and added a new constructor for the `Renderers` which include the context. The problem comes in cases like this where you are working on something that is not a CustomRenderer.

For these cases, I use James' Plugin **CurrentActivityPlugin** which will keep track of the current activity for you. Find it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity)

Hope this helps.-